# Kolourpaint - set default size for new image?

Tags: kolourpaint

In kolourpaint when I start program new blank image size is 1044 x 1481 px. I need to resize it each time. Is there a way to set different default size? Not found in menu settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and the version of KolourPaint is 17.12.3.

As shown in the image below, the "canvas" can be resized by dragging to whatever size one wants.

[image: Resizing the canvas]

This canvas size will apply subsequently when KolourPaint is opened by itself. Otherwise, KolourPaint will use a canvas size dependent on the size of the image being opened.